# Union of tables in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, union

I am performing union on two select statements but the result I am getting contains the random rows like some from table one and some from table two.But I want to get first all the rows from table one and then from table two.I am using MySql database.

```
  Table 1
==========================
s_no     Name        Marks
1       nikhil         25

  Table 2
====================
s_no  Name     Marks
1     Akhil     10  
2     Mark      20
1     Kim       40
```

Here is the query that I am using:

```
select * from (
      select t2.s_no,t2.name,t2.marks from table1 t2
  union all
      select t1.roll_no,t1.name,t1.marks from table1 t1
      ) a order by s_no desc
```

Here are the results:

```
  Actual result
=========================
s_no     Name     Marks
1        Akhil       10
1        nikhil  25  <<<
1        kim     40
2        mark        20

  required result
====================
s_no    Name     marks
1       Akhil      10
1       Kim        40
1       nikhil     25  <<<
2       mark       20
```

Comment: Add name also to the order by clause

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You need to add `order by s_no,name` in the last `select query`

```
(select * from table1)
union
(select * from table2) order by s_no,name
```